# wordpress image attachment slider?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, slide

I'm trying to learn more about wordpress.org. And I stumble a website that do some kind of a slider for image. I know some plugins but it doesn't work like that. the site have post that have multiple images that is displayed 1 at a time in a different page. [For example this site](http://begrizly.com/entertainment/celebrities/top-25-most-followed-women-of-instagram-outbrain/?utm_rcreplace_310=4898)

It has a start slide button at the 1st page of the post and when you start the slide, the url adds a # on the url. Something like this:

```
example.com/post/1
```

I tried googling it but cant find some function or I can't make it work.
I also tried `wp_get_attachment_image()` but no luck. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code here from the external site (or failing that, screenshots). Relying on a link (especially *shortened*) makes the question useless for anyone in the future once the link goes dead.

Comment: [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qN92x.jpg

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is not a slider. I went to the URL you mentioned and opened up the Google Chrome Console and found that although the plugin Flex Slider is installed, the "Top 25 Most..." feature is not using this. It seems to be custom JavaScript that uses iFrames within the navigation.

You can get this same effect by simply adding navigation buttons underneath the content in your page, with the click of each button taking you to another page.

Make your WordPress work easier, stick with Flex Slider, or other popular Wordpress slider plugins. http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Comment: thanks, I'll try that. is this a wordpress function?? like attachment?

Comment: Thank you sir, im trying to test if I can make it work like that. tyvm

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is to add an image repeater field to each post ( [ACF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) is great but the [repeater option](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/) is not free, however you can use [types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) which is free, check [its repeater documentation](https://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/repeating-fields/) ).

Now once you have the images retrieved for each post in its single page, you can use any jQuery library to sort them in a slider ( [Bootstrap's slider](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) is really good but many options are available: [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/), [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) ...).

However, if you are insisting on having each uploaded image in one page for each post in its single post, you can do it in another way.

Use a functionality called `page break` in the post content area but you'll have to add the whole post content ( texts and images ) in this content area.

Find below instructions:



**Backend:**

you need to add the following to your functions.php to show this button:

```
function my_add_next_page_button( $buttons, $id ){

    /* only add this for content editor */
    if ( 'content' != $id )
        return $buttons;

    /* add next page after more tag button */
    array_splice( $buttons, 13, 0, 'wp_page' );

    return $buttons;
}
add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'my_add_next_page_button', 1, 2 );
```

or you can use: `<!--nextpage-->` in your editor.

[image]



**Frontend:**

You'll need to add the following to your **functions.php** in order to generate the single post pagination:

```
function custom_wp_link_pages($args = '') {
    $defaults = array(
        'before' => '<div id="post-pagination">' . __(''),
        'after' => '</div>',
        'text_before' => '',
        'text_after' => '',
        'next_or_number' => 'next',
        'nextpagelink' => __('Next'),
        'previouspagelink' => __('Previous'),
        'pagelink' => '%',
        'echo' => 1
    );

    $r = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);
    $r = apply_filters('wp_link_pages_args', $r);
    extract($r, EXTR_SKIP);

    global $page, $numpages, $multipage, $more, $pagenow;

    $output = '';
    if ($multipage) {
        if ('number' == $next_or_number) {
            $output .= $before;
            for ($i = 1; $i < ( $numpages + 1 ); $i = $i + 1) {
                $j = str_replace('%', $i, $pagelink);
                $output .= ' ';
                if ($i != $page || ( (!$more ) && ( $page == 1 ) ))
                    $output .= _wp_link_page($i);
                else
                    $output .= '<span class="current-post-page">';

                $output .= $text_before . $j . $text_after;
                if ($i != $page || ( (!$more ) && ( $page == 1 ) ))
                    $output .= '</a>';
                else
                    $output .= '</span>';
            }
            $output .= $after;
        } else {
            if ($more) {
                $output .= $before;
                $i = $page - 1;
                if ($i && $more) {
                    $output .= _wp_link_page($i);
                    $output .= $text_before . $previouspagelink . $text_after . '</a>';
                }
                $i = $page + 1;
                if ($i <= $numpages && $more) {
                    $output .= _wp_link_page($i);
                    $output .= $text_before . $nextpagelink . $text_after . '</a>';
                }
                $output .= $after;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($echo)
        echo $output;

    return $output;
}
```

Now in your **single.php** inside the loop:

```
<?php
the_content();
custom_wp_link_pages();
?>
```

You'll get this layout:

[image]



The next button in each single post will have a link like this:
http://website.com/post-name/2 which will display content after the `page break` inserted until another one is added.

Refer to [wp_link_pages()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages) if anything went wrong.

I hope that helps :)

Comment: and the url #. my problem now is how to put a start slide button only(not the next/previous buttons) at the 1st page of the post? like on the site above. and I use the plugins you mentioned but I cant make it work, something on jquery slider. would it still be displayed like the site above?

Comment: Man you need to clarify what you clearly want to do, if you want to have an image slider your next and previous buttons will be used to navigate between images so the website link won't change. Now if you want to have each on image on a page for each post your next and previous buttons will be used to navigate between pages for the same post : http://example.com/post-name/1 & http://example.com/post-name/2 for example.

Comment: sorry sir, I think i'm on the right track now. My only problem now is how to have the start slide button on the first page of the post. in my code n ow it keeps showing "Next"  on the 1st page. I want to have a "start slide" button on the 1st page of the post  and display the  example.com/post-name/1 and display next and previous buttons on the succeeding pages example.com/post-name/2 , 3, 4, 5 .. how can I achieve it sir?